# C++ Sockets and stress testing

Tags: c++, sockets, testing, winsock2

I've written a very simple socket server in C++ (MinGW) using these common functions like

```
socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 )...
setsockopt( s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &OptVal, sizeof( OptVal ) )...
bind( s, ( struct sockaddr * ) &ServerAddress, sizeof( ServerAddress ) )...
listen( s, 10 )...
```

The handling of multiple client connections is done by

```
select( s, &FileDescriptorClient, NULL, NULL, &tv )...
accept( Server->GetSocketHandle(), (struct sockaddr*) &ClientAddress, &Length )...
```

Everything looked very good and pretty,... until I decided to **stress test** my server.

My first test was a very simple client which did only one thing: connect and disconnect in an endless loop - as fast as possible. Although this test was extremly simple it failed immediately.

It wasn't a too big surprise to me that the server will choke on so many toggeling connections, so I added a Sleep(5) (milliseconds) in the client before each connect and disconnect and everything was OK. For the moment.

My questions are:

- How do I handle these reconnects correct?
- And what is the proper way
  to stress test a socket server application?

Right now the procedure is as follows:

1. client: connects to server using connect(...)
2. server: the new connection is recognized by select(...) and accept(...). Every new connection is stored to a std::vector.
3. client: disconnects from server using closesocket(...) (MinGW...)
4. server: recv(...) reads 0 bytes what means the client has disconnected from server
5. server: performs a closesocket(...) and removes connection from std::vector
6. goto 1

As already mentioned: this will only work when I throttle the client with sleeps. As soon as I reduce the sleeping times, the server starts skipping pt. 4 (disconnects) and stockpiles open connections down the line.

What is the point I am missing?

Edit:

- server runs in a single thread
- client socket is non-blocking

Edit 2:

As requested: the source code (cut to a minimal version):

Server's main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Server.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket srv;

        while ( true )
        {
            srv.Open();
            srv.Run();
        }
    }
    catch( ServerException const &e )
    {
        std::cout << "failed to run the server" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Server.h:

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#define SOCKETBUFLEN 10

#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

class Exception : public std::exception
{
    private:
        std::string Message;
    public:
        template< typename ... Arguments >
        Exception( const char * AFormat, Arguments&& ... AArguments )
        {
            char Buffer[ 1024 ];
            sprintf( Buffer, AFormat, std::forward<Arguments>( AArguments ) ... );
            Message = std::string( Buffer );
        };
        const char* what() const noexcept{ return Message.c_str(); }
};

class ServerException : public Exception
{
    public:
        template< typename ... Arguments >
        ServerException( const char * AFormat, Arguments&& ... AArguments ) : Exception( AFormat, std::forward< Arguments >( AArguments ) ... ){}
};

class ClientException : public Exception
{
    public:
        template< typename ... Arguments >
        ClientException( const char * AFormat, Arguments&& ... AArguments ) : Exception( AFormat, std::forward< Arguments >( AArguments ) ... ){}
};

class Client
{
    public:
        Client();
        virtual ~Client();

        virtual bool Authenticate( const std::string & AClientId ) = 0;
        virtual bool Process( const std::string & AMessage ) = 0;
    protected:
        std::vector< std::string > Clients;
    private:
};

class ServerSocket;
class ClientSocket;
class Socket;

class ClientSockets
{
    private:
        ServerSocket *OwnerServer;
        fd_set FileDescriptorClient;
        std::vector< ClientSocket * > Items;
        std::vector< Socket * > SocketsRead;
        void Append( ClientSocket * );
        void OnClientConnect( SOCKET ASocketHandle, struct sockaddr_in AClientAddress );
    public:
        ClientSockets( ServerSocket * );
        int Count( void );
        void Remove( SOCKET ASocketHandle );
        bool HandleConnnections( void );
        void Read( void );
};

class Socket
{
    protected:
        SOCKET SocketHandle;
    public:
        Socket( SOCKET ASocketHandle = 0 ) { SocketHandle = ASocketHandle; };
        SOCKET GetSocketHandle( void ) { return SocketHandle; };
        virtual void Close( void ) = 0;
};

class ServerSocket : public Socket
{
    public:
        ServerSocket( const std::string &AHost = "127.0.0.1", const int &APort = 24442 );
        virtual ~ServerSocket();

        void Open( void );
        void Close( void ) {};
        void Run( void );

        fd_set FileDescriptorServer;
    private:
        std::string Host;
        int Port;
        ClientSockets *clientSockets;
};

class ClientSocket : public Socket
{
    private:
        ClientSockets *FClientSockets;
    public:
        ClientSocket( ClientSockets *, SOCKET ASocketHandle );
        virtual ~ClientSocket() {};

        void Close( void );
};

#endif // SERVER_H
```

Server.cpp:

```
#include "Server.h"

#include <cstring>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#define LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT 100

ServerSocket::ServerSocket( const std::string &AHost, const int &APort ) :
    Host( AHost ),
    Port( APort ),
    clientSockets( new ClientSockets( this ) ) {}

ServerSocket::~ServerSocket()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

void ServerSocket::Open( void )
{
    WSADATA wsa;

    if ( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &wsa ) != 0 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "WSAStartup failed" );
    }

    if ( ( SocketHandle = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: unable to get a socket handle. errno: %ld", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, errno );
    }

    char OptVal = 1;

    if ( setsockopt( SocketHandle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &OptVal, sizeof( OptVal ) ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: setsockopt failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress;

    memset( & ServerAddress, 0x0, sizeof( ServerAddress ) );

    ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( Host.c_str() );
    ServerAddress.sin_port = htons( Port );

    if ( bind( SocketHandle, ( struct sockaddr * ) &ServerAddress, sizeof( ServerAddress ) ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: binding server address failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    if ( listen( SocketHandle, 10 ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: listen socket failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    FD_ZERO( &FileDescriptorServer );
    FD_SET( SocketHandle, &FileDescriptorServer );

    std::cout << "socket server fd '" << SocketHandle << "' listening on " << Host << ":" << Port << std::endl;
}

void ServerSocket::Run( void )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << std::endl;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            if ( !clientSockets->HandleConnnections() )
            {
                continue;
            }

            clientSockets->Read();
        }
        catch( ServerException const &e )
        {
            int ErrorCode = WSAGetLastError();

            std::cout << "error while server running: " << e.what() << ", code: " << ErrorCode << std::endl;

            if ( ErrorCode == 10038 ) // no socket error
            {
                // continue; // not sure if this is the correct way to do...
            }

            // if ( ErrorCode == 10014 ) {} // bad address error
            // if ( ErrorCode == 10054 ) {} // connection reset by peer

            break;
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            std::cout << "some exception occurred" << std::endl;
        }
    } while ( true );
}

ClientSockets::ClientSockets( ServerSocket * AOwnerServer )
{
    OwnerServer = AOwnerServer;
}

void ClientSockets::Append( ClientSocket *AClientSocket )
{
    Items.push_back( AClientSocket );
}

int ClientSockets::Count( void )
{
    return Items.size();
}

bool ClientSockets::HandleConnnections( void )
{
    FD_ZERO( & FileDescriptorClient );

    SocketsRead.clear();
    SocketsRead.push_back( OwnerServer );

    for ( auto i : Items )
    {
        SocketsRead.push_back( i );
    }

    for ( auto Socket : SocketsRead )
    {
        if ( FD_ISSET( Socket->GetSocketHandle(), & OwnerServer->FileDescriptorServer ) )
        {
            FD_SET( Socket->GetSocketHandle(), & FileDescriptorClient );
        }
    }

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 10;
    tv.tv_usec = 3;

    int SocketChangedCount = 0;

    if ( ( SocketChangedCount = select( 0, &FileDescriptorClient, NULL, NULL, &tv ) ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: select failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    static int scc = 0;
    if ( scc != SocketChangedCount )
    {
        scc = SocketChangedCount;
        std::cout << "socket changes: " << SocketChangedCount << std::endl;
    }


    if ( FD_ISSET( OwnerServer->GetSocketHandle(), &FileDescriptorClient ) )
    {
        struct sockaddr_in ClientAddress;

        socklen_t Length = sizeof( ClientAddress );

        SOCKET SocketHandle = 0;

        if ( ( SocketHandle = accept( OwnerServer->GetSocketHandle(), (struct sockaddr*) &ClientAddress, &Length ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            throw ServerException( "%s: accept failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
        }
        else
        {
            OnClientConnect( SocketHandle, ClientAddress );
        }

        FD_SET( SocketHandle, &OwnerServer->FileDescriptorServer );
    }

    return ( SocketChangedCount > 0 );
}

void ClientSockets::OnClientConnect( SOCKET ASocketHandle, struct sockaddr_in AClientAddress )
{
#if LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT > 0
    static int ClientConnectionCounter = 0;

    if ( ClientConnectionCounter++ % LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "connect     fd: [" << ASocketHandle << "], serial: [" << ClientConnectionCounter << "], cnt: [" << Count() << "]" << std::endl;
    }
#endif

    ClientSocket *clientSocket = new ClientSocket( this, ASocketHandle );

    Append( clientSocket );
}

void ClientSockets::Read( void )
{
    for ( auto clientSocket : Items )
    {
        if ( FD_ISSET( clientSocket->GetSocketHandle(), &FileDescriptorClient ) )
        {
            char buf[ SOCKETBUFLEN + 1 ];
            memset( buf, 0x0, sizeof( buf ) );

            int BytesReceived = recv( clientSocket->GetSocketHandle(), buf, SOCKETBUFLEN, 0 );

            if ( BytesReceived > 0 )
            {
                std::string Message = ( std::string ) buf;

                if ( Message.substr( 0, 4 ) == "quit" )
                {
                    clientSocket->Close();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // ... do fancy stuff here...
                    std::cout << "read from socket: " << Message << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else if ( BytesReceived == 0 )
            {
                clientSocket->Close();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                throw ServerException( "reading data failed" );
            }
        }
    }
}



void ClientSockets::Remove( SOCKET ASocketHandle )
{
    FD_CLR( ASocketHandle, & FileDescriptorClient );

    std::vector< ClientSocket * >::iterator it =
        Items.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                Items.begin(),
                Items.end(),
                [ ASocketHandle ]( Socket *sock ){ return sock->GetSocketHandle() == ASocketHandle; }
            )
        );

    delete *it;
}


void ClientSocket::Close( void )
{
#if LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT > 0
    static int ClientDisconnectionCounter = 0;

    if ( ClientDisconnectionCounter++ % LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "disconnnect fd: [" << SocketHandle << "], serial: [" << ClientDisconnectionCounter << "], cnt: [" << FClientSockets->Count() << "]" << std::endl;
    }
#endif

    if ( closesocket( SocketHandle ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        throw ClientException( "closing socket failed: %ld", errno );
    }

    FClientSockets->Remove( SocketHandle );
}

ClientSocket::ClientSocket( ClientSockets *AClientSockets, SOCKET ASocketHandle ) :
    Socket( ASocketHandle ),
    FClientSockets( AClientSockets ) {}
```

The testing client application is very primitive: I used Embarcadero C++ Builder with a TClientSocket component which continuously toggles its connection state (in non-blocking-mode). 3 checkboxes are used to tell the application to run in loop mode (1), sleep before connect (2) and sleep before disconnect(3) and 1 TEdit is used to modify the sleep duration in Milliseconds.

The code of the cpp file is:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "UnitFormMain.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TFormMain *FormMain;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TFormMain::TFormMain(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner), Trigger( false ), sock( 0 )
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormMain::ClientSocket1Connect(TObject *Sender, TCustomWinSocket *Socket)

{
    static int ConnectionCounter = 0;

    if ( ConnectionCounter++ % 100 == 0 )
    {
        Memo1->Lines->Add( System::Sysutils::Format( "connectionCounter '%d'", ARRAYOFCONST(( ConnectionCounter )) ) );
    }

    if ( CheckBoxRunLoopComponent->Checked )
    {
        Trigger = true;
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormMain::ClientSocket1Disconnect(TObject *Sender, TCustomWinSocket *Socket)
{

    if ( CheckBoxRunLoopComponent->Checked )
    {
        Trigger = true;
    }

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormMain::ButtonToggleConnectionComponentClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    ClientSocket1->Active = !ClientSocket1->Active;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormMain::CheckBoxRunLoopComponentClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if ( dynamic_cast< TCheckBox * >( Sender )->Checked )
    {

        for (;;)
        {
            Application->ProcessMessages();

            if ( !dynamic_cast< TCheckBox * >( Sender )->Checked )
            {
                break;
            }

            ToggleConnection();
        }
    }
}

void TFormMain::ToggleConnection( void )
{
    if ( Trigger )
    {
        Trigger = false;

        if ( ClientSocket1->Active )
        {
            if ( CheckBoxSleepOnDisconnect )
            {
                Sleep( StrToInt( Edit1->Text ) );
            }

            ClientSocket1->Close();

        }
        else
        {
            if ( CheckBoxSleepOnConnect->Checked )
            {
                Sleep( StrToInt( Edit1->Text ) );
            }

            ClientSocket1->Open();
        }
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Way more interesting is the output of the test run (server):

Each 100th toggle is protocolled.
"cnt" is the number of connections in the std::vector<>.

The test started with 5 milliseconds sleep on each toggle. Somewhere around the 1500th toggling I decreased the sleeping time to 1 millisecond which lead into an immediate increase of active connections in the servers list. A few thousand connections later `select()` fails with `10038`.

```
socket server fd '276' listening on 127.0.0.1:24442
void ServerSocket::Run()
socket changes: 1
connect     fd: [280], serial: [1], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [280], serial: [1], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [284], serial: [101], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [284], serial: [101], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [280], serial: [201], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [280], serial: [201], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [288], serial: [301], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [288], serial: [301], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [292], serial: [401], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [292], serial: [401], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [296], serial: [501], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [296], serial: [501], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [308], serial: [601], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [308], serial: [601], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [296], serial: [701], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [296], serial: [701], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [296], serial: [801], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [296], serial: [801], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [288], serial: [901], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [288], serial: [901], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [300], serial: [1001], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [300], serial: [1001], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [312], serial: [1101], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [312], serial: [1101], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [300], serial: [1201], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [300], serial: [1201], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [300], serial: [1301], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [300], serial: [1301], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [280], serial: [1401], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [280], serial: [1401], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [280], serial: [1501], cnt: [0]
disconnnect fd: [280], serial: [1501], cnt: [1]
connect     fd: [316], serial: [1601], cnt: [0]
socket changes: 2
disconnnect fd: [316], serial: [1601], cnt: [2]
socket changes: 1
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
connect     fd: [312], serial: [1701], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [312], serial: [1701], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [324], serial: [1801], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [312], serial: [1801], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [324], serial: [1901], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [324], serial: [1901], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [320], serial: [2001], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [320], serial: [2001], cnt: [4]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
connect     fd: [336], serial: [2101], cnt: [3]
disconnnect fd: [336], serial: [2101], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [344], serial: [2201], cnt: [3]
disconnnect fd: [344], serial: [2201], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [344], serial: [2301], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [336], serial: [2301], cnt: [4]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
connect     fd: [344], serial: [2401], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [336], serial: [2401], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [344], serial: [2501], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [344], serial: [2501], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [344], serial: [2601], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [344], serial: [2601], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [332], serial: [2701], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [332], serial: [2701], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [344], serial: [2801], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [332], serial: [2801], cnt: [4]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
connect     fd: [328], serial: [2901], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [324], serial: [2901], cnt: [4]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
connect     fd: [328], serial: [3001], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [324], serial: [3001], cnt: [4]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
connect     fd: [328], serial: [3101], cnt: [3]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
disconnnect fd: [324], serial: [3101], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [324], serial: [3201], cnt: [3]
disconnnect fd: [324], serial: [3201], cnt: [4]
connect     fd: [324], serial: [3301], cnt: [3]
disconnnect fd: [324], serial: [3301], cnt: [4]
socket changes: 2
socket changes: 1
error while server running: bool ClientSockets::HandleConnnections(): select failed, code: 10038
socket server fd '324' listening on 127.0.0.1:24442
void ServerSocket::Run()
socket changes: 0
```

In this protocol I also see that `select()` returns a value > 1 ("Socket changes: n") which means that more than 1 socket changed its status. I think this might be the pointer to the correct solution, but right now I don't know how to handle this the right way.

Edit 3: Blocking/Noneblocking: In CPPBuilder you can use these design time components where you can set the properties at design time:

[image: TClientSocktet property editor]

Comment: Please post, if possible, all your code.  Thx.  If that's too complex, please aim to put together a [MCVE].

Comment: You must be on Windows (inferring from MINGW), when closing the port, it is not readily available but sits in a `TIME_WAIT` state for a length of time, before becoming really available.  This state is configurable at the registry (don't have easy reference atm).  This will impose a max rate of open/close calls in your system.

Comment: Also you can use a port viewer util to see what is happening, `netstat -ano` or [SysInternals TcpView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/)

Comment: @PaulSanders: I added some code.

Comment: Where does the code make sockets non-blocking?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: in C++Builder you can use design time components in which you can set some properties while designing. In this case ClientSocket1 is an object of the design time component TClientSocket. I've added a screen shot above.

Comment: @ChrisO I too thought that might be a factor, but I didn't see that in my tests.  I guess things have improved since the days of SCO Unix (where it was a real pain).

Comment: @Herwig C++ builder is somewhat an obscure thing these days. I would build it using `boost::asio` which is the basis for the next C++ networking library. It should take a hundred lines or less, not these pages of code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with your code - it's too complicated for me to follow properly, so instead, I've posted some code of my own that works correctly which you can use as a guide.

This code works fine using `Sleep(1)` in the client (although this doesn't do quite what you probably think it does).  There are some further notes below.

```
#define FD_SETSIZE      4096

#include <WinSock2.h>                   // ** before** windows.h
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <assert.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

const int port = 24442;
std::set <SOCKET> connected_sockets;

// main
int main (char argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int err = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsadata);
    if (err)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed, error: " << err << std::endl;
        return 255;
    }

    char buf [512];
    bool is_client = argc > 1 && _stricmp (argv [1], "client") == 0;

    if (is_client)
    {
        int lap = 0;
        for ( ; ; )
        {
            // Client
            SOCKET skt = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            assert (skt != INVALID_SOCKET);

            sockaddr_in server_address = { };
            server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
            server_address.sin_port = htons (port);
            inet_pton (AF_INET, "192.168.1.2", &server_address.sin_addr);

            std::cout << ++lap << ": Connecting..." << std::endl;
            int err = connect (skt, (const sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof (server_address));

            if (err)
            {
                std::cout << "connect() failed, error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
                Sleep (50);
                continue;
            }

            memset (buf, 'Q', sizeof (buf));
            std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;

            if (send (skt, buf, sizeof (buf), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                std::cout << "send() failed, error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Disconnecting..." << std::endl;
            closesocket (skt);
            Sleep (1);
        }

        WSACleanup ();
        return 0;
    }

    // Server
    SOCKET listener_skt = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert (listener_skt != INVALID_SOCKET);
    sockaddr_in receive_address = { };
    receive_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    receive_address.sin_port = htons (port);
    receive_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind (listener_skt, (const sockaddr *) &receive_address, sizeof (receive_address)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "bind failed , error: " << errno << std::endl;
        return 255;
    }

    if (listen (listener_skt, 256) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "listen() failed, error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
        return 255;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening..." << std::endl;

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        fd_set read_fds;
        FD_ZERO (&read_fds);
        FD_SET (listener_skt, &read_fds);    // listener_skt must be first

        int n_fds = 0;
        for (auto skt : connected_sockets)
        {
            FD_SET (skt, &read_fds);
            if (++n_fds >= FD_SETSIZE - 1)
                break;
        }

        n_fds = select (0, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (n_fds <= 0)
        {
            if (n_fds < 0)
                std::cout << "select failed, error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        int i = 0;
        if (read_fds.fd_array [i] == listener_skt)
        {
            SOCKET skt = accept (listener_skt, NULL, 0);
            if (skt == SOCKET_ERROR)
                std::cout << "accept() failed, error: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Accepted connection on socket: " << skt << std::endl;
                connected_sockets.insert (skt);
            }
            ++i;
        }

        while (i < n_fds)
        {
            SOCKET skt = read_fds.fd_array [i];
            int nbytes = recv (skt, buf, sizeof (buf), 0);
            if (nbytes > 0)
                std::cout << "Received " << nbytes << " bytes on socket " << skt << std::endl;
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Socket " << skt << " disconnected, code: " << nbytes << std::endl;
                closesocket (skt);
                connected_sockets.erase (skt);
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }

    closesocket (listener_skt);
    WSACleanup ();
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

`test_program` - to run as a server

`test_program client` - to run as a client

Notes:

1. You have to #define (and then respect) `FD_SETSIZE` before you #include `WinSock2.h`.  Your code doesn't do this (= potential memory overwrite, which may be one of the things that is causing you trouble).
2. Your `backlog` parameter to `listen()` is too small and will result in clients being told that they cannot connect when the server is busy (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen)).  I went for 256 but the value you choose should be governed by your use-case and by test results.
3. A better stress test (which is one of the questions you asked) is to have several clients peppering the server with connection requests at once, with (I would suggest) a more realistic `Sleep` time in the client.  I tried 5 clients with `Sleep(50)` and it ran for 15 minutes or more without incident.
4. A `std::set` is a much better way for the server to keep track of its connected `SOCKET`s than a `vector`, see code.  It's very much what `std::set` was designed to do.

Hopefully this points the way.  Let me know if you have any questions (I like writing networking code :).

Answer (score 0):

My code had a couple of very serious issues and now I think I got them fixed. Maybe.

Four major changes had to be done on the server.

**Change #1: calling accept() only once when select() returns 2 is wrong.**

I already thought that my original code is wrong when I do not take any action when select() returns a value greater than 1. Normally this (almost) never happens, therefore I have this error in all my socket applications of the past decade without any effect. So I changed the code:

```
int SocketChangedCount = 0;

if ( ( SocketChangedCount = select( 0, &FileDescriptorClient, NULL, NULL, &tv ) ) == -1 )
{
    throw ServerException( "%s: select failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
}

if ( FD_ISSET( OwnerServer->GetSocketHandle(), &FileDescriptorClient ) )
{
    struct sockaddr_in ClientAddress;

    socklen_t Length = sizeof( ClientAddress );

    SOCKET SocketHandle = 0;

    // change N° 1:
    // the return value of select is the number of new connections.
    // therefore we need to call accept for EACH new connection.
    // this issue did never light up, because the connections have
    // to be established almost simultaneously to trigger this issue.

    for ( int i = 0; i < SocketChangedCount; ++i )
    {
        if ( ( SocketHandle = accept( OwnerServer->GetSocketHandle(), (struct sockaddr*) &ClientAddress, &Length ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            throw ServerException( "%s: accept failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
        }
        else
        {
            OnClientConnect( SocketHandle, ClientAddress );
        }

        FD_SET( SocketHandle, &OwnerServer->FileDescriptorServer );
    }
}
```

**Change #2: Although it wasn't the main problem the backlog size was obviously to small:**

```
// change N° 2:
// a backlog parameter of "10" is not enough. SOMAXCONN should be the preferable value
// if ( listen( SocketHandle, 10 ) == -1 )
if ( listen( SocketHandle, SOMAXCONN ) == -1 )
{
    throw ServerException( "%s: listen socket failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
}
```

**Change #3: I changed the std::vector into a std::unordered_map:**

```
    // change N° 3:
    std::unordered_map< SOCKET, ClientSocket * > Items;
    // std::vector< Socket * > SocketsRead;
```

By chance this also fixed a bug that I did not even notice before: the deletion of logged off client was simply wrong:

```
void ClientSockets::Remove( SOCKET ASocketHandle )
{
    FD_CLR( ASocketHandle, & FileDescriptorClient );

/*
    // whatever this code did: it was wrong
    std::vector< ClientSocket * >::iterator it =
        Items.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                Items.begin(),
                Items.end(),
                [ ASocketHandle ]( Socket *sock ){ return sock->GetSocketHandle() == ASocketHandle; }
            )
        );

    delete *it;
*/

    std::unordered_map< SOCKET, ClientSocket * >::iterator it = Items.find( ASocketHandle );

    if ( it != Items.end() )
    {
        Items.erase( it );
    }
}
```

**Change #4: Last but not least: broke up too early**

Whenever a client disconnected I stopped the loop with a break. Stupid me.

```
void ClientSockets::Read( void )
{
    for ( auto clientSocket : Items )
    {
        if ( FD_ISSET( clientSocket.first, &FileDescriptorClient ) )
        {
            char buf[ SOCKETBUFLEN + 1 ];
            memset( buf, 0x0, sizeof( buf ) );

            int BytesReceived = recv( clientSocket.first, buf, SOCKETBUFLEN, 0 );

            if ( BytesReceived > 0 )
            {
                std::string Message = ( std::string ) buf;

                if ( Message.substr( 0, 4 ) == "quit" )
                {
                    clientSocket.second->Close();
                    continue;
                    // break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // ... do fancy stuff here...
                    std::cout << "read from socket: " << Message << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else if ( BytesReceived == 0 )
            {
                clientSocket.second->Close();
                // change N° 4:
                // breaking the loop is a really bad idea
                continue;
                // break;
            }
            else
            {
                throw ServerException( "reading data failed" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank to you guys I was finally able to run my stress test application and found a couple of issues I would never had found.

If someone else likes to do something like this: Here is the fixed code:

Header:

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#define SOCKETBUFLEN 10

#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

class Exception : public std::exception
{
    private:
        std::string Message;
    public:
        template< typename ... Arguments >
        Exception( const char * AFormat, Arguments&& ... AArguments )
        {
            char Buffer[ 1024 ];
            sprintf( Buffer, AFormat, std::forward<Arguments>( AArguments ) ... );
            Message = std::string( Buffer );
        };
        const char* what() const noexcept{ return Message.c_str(); }
};

class ServerException : public Exception
{
    public:
        template< typename ... Arguments >
        ServerException( const char * AFormat, Arguments&& ... AArguments ) : Exception( AFormat, std::forward< Arguments >( AArguments ) ... ){}
};

class ClientException : public Exception
{
    public:
        template< typename ... Arguments >
        ClientException( const char * AFormat, Arguments&& ... AArguments ) : Exception( AFormat, std::forward< Arguments >( AArguments ) ... ){}
};

class Client
{
    public:
        Client();
        virtual ~Client();

        virtual bool Authenticate( const std::string & AClientId ) = 0;
        virtual bool Process( const std::string & AMessage ) = 0;
    private:
};

class ServerSocket;
class ClientSocket;
class Socket;

class ClientSockets
{
    private:
        ServerSocket *OwnerServer;
        fd_set FileDescriptorClient;
        // change N° 3:
        std::unordered_map< SOCKET, ClientSocket * > Items;
        // std::vector< Socket * > SocketsRead;
        void Append( ClientSocket * );
        void OnClientConnect( SOCKET ASocketHandle, struct sockaddr_in AClientAddress );
    public:
        ClientSockets( ServerSocket * );
        int Count( void );
        void Remove( SOCKET ASocketHandle );
        bool HandleConnnections( void );
        void Read( void );
};

class Socket
{
    protected:
        SOCKET SocketHandle;
    public:
        Socket( SOCKET ASocketHandle = 0 ) { SocketHandle = ASocketHandle; };
        SOCKET GetSocketHandle( void ) { return SocketHandle; };
        virtual void Close( void ) = 0;
};

class ServerSocket : public Socket
{
    public:
        ServerSocket( const std::string &AHost = "127.0.0.1", const int &APort = 24442 );
        virtual ~ServerSocket();

        void Open( void );
        void Close( void ) {};
        void Run( void );

        fd_set FileDescriptorServer;
    private:
        std::string Host;
        int Port;
        ClientSockets *clientSockets;
};

class ClientSocket : public Socket
{
    private:
        ClientSockets *FClientSockets;
    public:
        ClientSocket( ClientSockets *, SOCKET ASocketHandle );
        virtual ~ClientSocket() {};

        void Close( void );
};

#endif // SERVER_H
```

Source:

```
#include "Server.h"

#include <cstring>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#define LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT 100

ServerSocket::ServerSocket( const std::string &AHost, const int &APort ) :
    Host( AHost ),
    Port( APort ),
    clientSockets( new ClientSockets( this ) ) {}

ServerSocket::~ServerSocket()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

void ServerSocket::Open( void )
{
    WSADATA wsa;

    if ( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &wsa ) != 0 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "WSAStartup failed" );
    }

    if ( ( SocketHandle = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: unable to get a socket handle. errno: %ld", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, errno );
    }

    char OptVal = 1;

    if ( setsockopt( SocketHandle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &OptVal, sizeof( OptVal ) ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: setsockopt failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress;

    memset( & ServerAddress, 0x0, sizeof( ServerAddress ) );

    ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( Host.c_str() );
    ServerAddress.sin_port = htons( Port );

    if ( bind( SocketHandle, ( struct sockaddr * ) &ServerAddress, sizeof( ServerAddress ) ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: binding server address failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    // change N° 2:
    // a backlog parameter of "10" is not enough. SOMAXCONN should be the preferable value
    // if ( listen( SocketHandle, 10 ) == -1 )
    if ( listen( SocketHandle, SOMAXCONN ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: listen socket failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    FD_ZERO( &FileDescriptorServer );
    FD_SET( SocketHandle, &FileDescriptorServer );

    std::cout << "socket server fd '" << SocketHandle << "' listening on " << Host << ":" << Port << std::endl;
}

void ServerSocket::Run( void )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << std::endl;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            if ( !clientSockets->HandleConnnections() )
            {
                continue;
            }

            clientSockets->Read();
        }
        catch( ServerException const &e )
        {
            int ErrorCode = WSAGetLastError();

            std::cout << "error while server running: " << e.what() << ", code: " << ErrorCode << std::endl;

            if ( ErrorCode == 10038 ) // no socket error
            {
                // continue; // not sure if this is the correct way to do...
            }

            // if ( ErrorCode == 10014 ) {} // bad address error
            // if ( ErrorCode == 10054 ) {} // connection reset by peer

            break;
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            std::cout << "some exception occurred" << std::endl;
        }
    } while ( true );
}

ClientSockets::ClientSockets( ServerSocket * AOwnerServer )
{
    OwnerServer = AOwnerServer;
}

void ClientSockets::Append( ClientSocket *AClientSocket )
{
    Items.insert( std::make_pair( AClientSocket->GetSocketHandle(), AClientSocket ) );
}

int ClientSockets::Count( void )
{
    return Items.size();
}

bool ClientSockets::HandleConnnections( void )
{
    FD_ZERO( & FileDescriptorClient );

    std::unordered_map< SOCKET, Socket *> SocketsRead;
    SocketsRead.insert( std::make_pair( OwnerServer->GetSocketHandle(), OwnerServer ) );

    for ( auto client : Items )
    {
        SocketsRead.insert( client );
    }

    for ( auto Socket : SocketsRead )
    {
        if ( FD_ISSET( Socket.first, & OwnerServer->FileDescriptorServer ) )
        {
            FD_SET( Socket.first, & FileDescriptorClient );
        }
    }

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 3;

    int SocketChangedCount = 0;

    if ( ( SocketChangedCount = select( 0, &FileDescriptorClient, NULL, NULL, &tv ) ) == -1 )
    {
        throw ServerException( "%s: select failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    }

    if ( FD_ISSET( OwnerServer->GetSocketHandle(), &FileDescriptorClient ) )
    {
        struct sockaddr_in ClientAddress;

        socklen_t Length = sizeof( ClientAddress );

        SOCKET SocketHandle = 0;

        // change N° 1:
        // the return value of select is the number of new connections.
        // therefore we need to call accept for EACH new connection.
        // this issue did never light up, because the connections have
        // to be established almost simultaneously to trigger this issue.

        for ( int i = 0; i < SocketChangedCount; ++i )
        {
            if ( ( SocketHandle = accept( OwnerServer->GetSocketHandle(), (struct sockaddr*) &ClientAddress, &Length ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
            {
                throw ServerException( "%s: accept failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
            }
            else
            {
                OnClientConnect( SocketHandle, ClientAddress );
            }

            FD_SET( SocketHandle, &OwnerServer->FileDescriptorServer );
        }
    }

    return ( SocketChangedCount > 0 );
}

void ClientSockets::OnClientConnect( SOCKET ASocketHandle, struct sockaddr_in AClientAddress )
{
#if LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT > 0
    static int ClientConnectionCounter = 0;

    if ( ClientConnectionCounter++ % LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "connect     fd: [" << ASocketHandle << "], serial: [" << ClientConnectionCounter << "], cnt: [" << Count() << "]" << std::endl;
    }
#endif

    ClientSocket *clientSocket = new ClientSocket( this, ASocketHandle );

    Append( clientSocket );
}

void ClientSockets::Read( void )
{
    for ( auto clientSocket : Items )
    {
        if ( FD_ISSET( clientSocket.first, &FileDescriptorClient ) )
        {
            char buf[ SOCKETBUFLEN + 1 ];
            memset( buf, 0x0, sizeof( buf ) );

            int BytesReceived = recv( clientSocket.first, buf, SOCKETBUFLEN, 0 );

            if ( BytesReceived > 0 )
            {
                std::string Message = ( std::string ) buf;

                if ( Message.substr( 0, 4 ) == "quit" )
                {
                    clientSocket.second->Close();
                    continue;
                    // break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // ... do fancy stuff here...
                    std::cout << "read from socket: " << Message << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else if ( BytesReceived == 0 )
            {
                clientSocket.second->Close();
                // change N° 4:
                // breaking the loop is a really bad idea
                continue;
                // break;
            }
            else
            {
                throw ServerException( "reading data failed" );
            }
        }
    }
}



void ClientSockets::Remove( SOCKET ASocketHandle )
{
    FD_CLR( ASocketHandle, & FileDescriptorClient );

/*
    // whatever this code did: it was wrong
    std::vector< ClientSocket * >::iterator it =
        Items.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                Items.begin(),
                Items.end(),
                [ ASocketHandle ]( Socket *sock ){ return sock->GetSocketHandle() == ASocketHandle; }
            )
        );

    delete *it;
*/

    std::unordered_map< SOCKET, ClientSocket * >::iterator it = Items.find( ASocketHandle );

    if ( it != Items.end() )
    {
        Items.erase( it );
    }
}


void ClientSocket::Close( void )
{
#if LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT > 0
    static int ClientDisconnectionCounter = 0;

    if ( ClientDisconnectionCounter++ % LOG_CONNECTION_AMOUNT == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "disconnnect fd: [" << SocketHandle << "], serial: [" << ClientDisconnectionCounter << "], cnt: [" << FClientSockets->Count() << "]" << std::endl;
    }
#endif

    if ( closesocket( SocketHandle ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        throw ClientException( "closing socket failed: %ld", errno );
    }

    FClientSockets->Remove( SocketHandle );
}

ClientSocket::ClientSocket( ClientSockets *AClientSockets, SOCKET ASocketHandle ) :
    Socket( ASocketHandle ),
    FClientSockets( AClientSockets ) {}
```

Main.cpp remains unchained. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good, glad you are up and running, and since my answer gave you what you needed, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), that's what we do here.  I made one change to my code - I replaced `std::unordered_map` with `std::set`, as it is simpler and more efficient, see code.  I suggest you do the same. Happy hacking.

Comment: And I'm sorry to have to tell you that it is not correct to call `accept` in a loop like that (wherever did you get that idea?) - you run the risk of it blocking if you do. `select` returns _the number of socket descriptors which will not block when read_ in the set passed in. The backlog parameter takes care of multiple connections arriving at the same time and all you have to do is loop round and call `select` again to be notified that there are more pending. Please take a more careful look at the code I posted, which is doing it right, and please be more alert when you read the docs.  Thx